# "Il ai situé" or "Il est situé"

Tags: grammaire, auxiliaires

The verb "Situer" is not included in DRS MRS VANDERTAMP rule
Is it conjugated with "etre"?

---

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Situé can be used with either *être* and *avoir* depending on the form used:

- Transitive form (*[situer](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/situer.php)*, uses *avoir*):

  > *Je l'ai situé dans le mauvais pays.* (I located it in the wrong country)

  but note that the passive voice always uses *être* as an additional auxiliary:

  > *Le col des Limouches a été situé par erreur sur la commune de Peyrus.*
- Pronominal form (*[se situer](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/du/verbe/se_situer.php)*, uses *être*):

  > *Je me situe dans la moyenne*
  >
  > *Le cours de l'or s'était situé à son maximum depuis dix ans*
- Past participle used adjectivally

  > *Je suis situé dans le chaos*, Paul Claudel, *Le risque de la mer*, 1900

Answer (score 4):

*Il a situé* is the correct form when *avoir* is used as an auxiliary. *Il ai situé* is recognized, based on pronunciation, as a mispelling of *Il est situé*. (Although it could also be a mispelling of the subjunctive *Il ait situé*.)

Note that transitive verbs are always conjugated with *avoir*:

> Il a situé l'avion sur la carte grace au radar. (He located the plane on the map using the radar.)

But in many cases, the past participle *situé* is used as an adjective when bound to the subject with state verbs (*verbes d'état*) such as *être*:

> Cette maison est située dans un vallon. (This house is located in a valley.)

Pour plus d'exemples voir :

https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/situer

http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/situer